# How to display data from mongodb on client side?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I have created a chat app using nodejs/express, mongodb, reactjs. When I type in the chat box and on clicking send button the data get's stored inside mongodb but how can I display it on client side. In code below I am not able to display it on client side. In server.js I am not able to emit the messages. What I am doing wrong in server.js ? The data is not reaching frontend from backend/database.

Code:

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const socket = require('socket.io');
const message = require('./model/message')

const app = express();

const mongoURI = require('./config/keys').mongoURI;

mongoose.connect(mongoURI, {useNewUrlParser: true})
  .then()
  .catch( err => console.log(err));

let db = mongoose.connection;

const port = 5000;

let server = app.listen(5000, function(){
  console.log('server is running on port 5000')
});

let io =  socket(server);

io.on("connection", function(socket){
  console.log("Socket Connection Established with ID :"+ socket.id)

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('User Disconnected');
  });

  let chat = db.collection('chat');

      socket.on('SEND_MESSAGE', function(data){
        let message = data.message;
        let date = data.date;

        // Check for name and message
        if(message !== '' || date !== ''){
            // Insert message
            chat.insert({message: message, date:date}, function(){
                socket.emit('output', [data]);
            });
        }
    });

    //Code below this is not working:
    chat.find().limit(100).sort({_id:1}).toArray(function(err, res){
      if(err){
          throw err;
      }
      // Emit the messages
      socket.emit('RECEIVE_MESSAGE', res);
    });

})
```

chat.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './chat.css'
import io from "socket.io-client";

export default class Chat extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            message: '',
            date: '',
            messages: []
        };

        const socket = io('localhost:5000');

        this.sendMessage = event => {
            event.preventDefault();

            if(this.state.message !== ''){
                socket.emit('SEND_MESSAGE', {
                    message: this.state.message,
                    date: Date.now()
                });
                this.setState({ message: '', date: '' });
            }
        };

        socket.emit('RECEIVE_MESSAGE', data => {
            addMessage(data);
        });

        const addMessage = data => {
            console.log(data);
            this.setState({
              messages: [...this.state.messages, data],
            });
            console.log(this.state.message);
            console.log(this.state.messages);
        };

    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
                <div id="status"></div>
                <div id="chat">
                    <div className="card">
                        <div id="messages" className="card-block">
                            {this.state.messages.map((message, index) => {
                                    return (
                                        <div key={index} className="msgBox"><p className="msgText">{message.message}</p></div>
                                    )
                            })}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="column">
                            <input id="inputmsg" type="text" placeholder="Enter Message...."
                            value={this.state.message} onChange={ev => this.setState({message: ev.target.value})}/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="column2">
                            <button id="send" className="button" onClick={this.sendMessage}>Send</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Screenshot of mongo shell:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose documentation specifies the correct usage of .find() method . You can find it [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find).

To cut the chase you need to give the method an object model that you are looking for. So for example if you were looking for objects with specific date field you could use:

```
chat.find({ "date": <some-date> }, function(err, objects) { ... });
```

If you want to fetch all object from the collection you can use:

```
chat.find({}, function(err, objects) { ... });
```

Comment: But what is wrong with this -> `chat.find().limit(100).sort({_id:1}).toArray(function(err, res){`

Comment: You are passing _null_ to the _find_ method, which has undefined consequences. You need to give it an object that it can analyze and give you the results you want.

Comment: Has this solved your problem? If so mark the answer as correct an question as closed.

Comment: Your answer is not solving the problem you can see the similar code here -> https://github.com/bradtraversy/mongochat/blob/5be0365dadcb677d94aff51d558216dc14aeb2de/server.js#L22